# Why do I get an extra trailing space and how to get rid of it?

Tags: ruby, oop, class-level

I am new to ruby and I can't understand why I after running this code I get an extra empty line as a result as a part of the output. I am using Ruby 2.5.3

```
class Card
  attr_accessor :rank, :suit

  def initialize(rank,suit)
    @rank = rank
    @suit = suit
  end

  def output_card
    puts "#{self.rank} of #{self.suit}"
  end

  def self.random_card
    suit = ["hearts", "spades", "clubs", "diamonds"]
    Card.new(rand(1..13), suit.sample)
  end
end

class Deck
  def initialize
    d = 0
    @cards =[]
    while d < 13
      @cards << Card.random_card
      d += 1
    end
  end

  def shuffle
    @cards.shuffle!
  end

  def output
    @cards.each do |card|
      card.output_card
    end
  end

  def deal
    self.shuffle
    dealing = @cards.shift
    puts "#{dealing.output_card}"
  end
end

deck = Deck.new
deck.deal
```

The above will give me this result:

```
[ENV]:/vagrant/OOP $ ruby card.rb
6 of clubs

[ENV]:/vagrant/OOP $
```

As you can see there is an extra line, and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs of `puts`:

> Writes a newline after any that do not already end with a newline sequence.

In `Deck.deal` you have `puts "#{dealing.output_card}"`. `Card#output_card` is defined as:

```
def output_card
  puts "#{self.rank} of #{self.suit}"
end
```

I.e., `Card#output_card` is already printing with a new line at the end. The return value of this method, which is the return value of `puts`, which in turn per the docs is `nil`, is then printed in `Deck.deal`, resulting in an empty line being printed.

In short, you're printing twice, where the second `puts` results in the additional line.

I suggest you remove `puts` from `Card` as it should not have a notion of printing itself. That's the job of `Deck`. I would change `Card#output_card` to be `Card#to_s` and just return the string you're constructing rather than `puts`ing it. Then you can rely on the fact that `puts` will call `#to_s` on the object being printed.

```
class Card
  # ...

  def to_s
    "#{self.rank} of #{self.suit}"
  end

  # ...
end

class Deck
  # ...

  def output
    @cards.each do |card|
      puts card
    end
  end

  def deal
    self.shuffle
    puts @cards.shift
  end
end
```

Comment: @HmejiaintheBay I see you're new to Stack Overflow. Would you mind accepting my answer as the correct one then? Thanks!

Comment: I just did that @fphilipe Thanks for the nudge, you are right.  I am very new here.